# Cordova config.xml preference android-installLocation

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

```
 <platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
</platform>
```

Preference for android install location inside config.xml does not work.
It is not passed inside the android manifest xml with prepare or build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android installLocation when building with cordova cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712129/android-installlocation-when-building-with-cordova-cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found in this issue was a plugin that make it possible to pass preferences from the config.cml to the android manifest, that are not passed automatically.

**cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config**
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config